# r ggplot plotting boundary line with 95% of all values below it

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a boundary line on a graph. I am currently plotting using the following function which gets me the 95% interval using a spline function:

```
g <- ggplot(m17d3, aes(x=Carbon, y=yield, col=Node, shape=Node)) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_manual(values=graypal) + 
    scale_shape_manual(values=c(2,17,15,18,0,4,3,1,16)) +
    ylab(expression(paste("Yield (kg/",ha^{-1},")"))) +
    xlab("Carbon (% by weight)") +
    theme(legend.position="none") +
    geom_smooth(aes(group=1), se=T, method=lm,
                formula = y ~ splines::bs(x,2), span=0.5, level=0.95) +
    ylim(c(0,9000))
```

Which gives me the following graph:[image]

What I would like is to split the x axis into 10 and select/plot points which are mean + 3 s.t.d. and above (in red and sorry for the slightly off position): 
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure that this description is enough to specify a line. I can imagine many lines that have 95% of the points on one side, and they could easily be very wiggly. Do you have a specific method in mind that you have a problem with implementation for?

Comment: I have modified the answer to say, for example, one method would be to split the x axis into 10 segments, and select the values above mean + 3 s.t.d.

Comment: how important is it to you that the line be anchored at zero?

Comment: It is not (why I removed it in the main question text too). I am currently trying to get it to work by splitting the data into 10 bins of equal width and calculating mean + 3.s.t.d. for each. This gives me a line I should be able to plot as a separate geom object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to plot it using this:

```
m17carbon$group <- as.factor(as.numeric(cut(m17carbon$Carbon, 30)))
summar_carb <- m17carbon 
%>% group_by(group) 
%>% summarise(y_mean=mean(yield), y_sd=sd(yield),c_mean =mean(Carbon,na.rm=T) ,n =n())

summar_carb$yield_2sd <- summar_carb$y_mean + summar_carb$y_sd*2

g <- ggplot() 
+ geom_point(data=m17d3, aes(x=Carbon, y=yield, col=Node, shape=Node)) 
+ scale_color_manual(values=graypal) 
+ scale_shape_manual(values=c(2,17,15,18,0,4,3,1,16)) 
+ ylab(expression(paste("Yield (kg/",ha^{-1},")"))) +xlab("Carbon (% by weight)") 
+ ggtitle("Yield potential from soil organic carbon") 
+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

g + geom_smooth(data=summary_c, aes(x=c_mean, y=yield_2sd), 
               se=FALSE, method=lm, formula = y ~ splines::bs(x,6))
```

Results in this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the values of your red function as a column in your data frame? Then you could plot the points and the lines on the same plot. A trivial example with mtcars...

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + geom_line(aes(x = mpg, y = hp))
```